# Check if input starts with X, alert and clear if not

Tags: jquery, validation

```
showAlert = false;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.indexOf('+') == 0) {
      $(this).val(''); // clear input 
      showAlert=true; // alert user
      if (showAlert==true)
        {
           console.log ("Phone number must start with +");
           showAlert = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I want the phone number input filed to ONLY with `+` but display the alert ONLY once... my code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i think you forgot to add $ in front of clear input syntax `(this).val('');` would be `$(this).val('');`

Comment: added, but still...the alert doesn't display as expected..it either doesn't display or displays more than once

Comment: i think instead of `value.indexOf('+') == 0` try `value.indexOf('+') == -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link

[Click here](http://jsbin.com/qikasoni/1)

You should match it with !="0"

This should be your Jquery

```
var show="";
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.indexOf('+') != 0) {
      $(this).val(''); 
      if(show=="")
        {
      alert("Phone number must start with +"); 
          }
      show="1";
    }
});
```

Because you want alert only once

Answer (score 1):

You missed the $ before `(this).val('');` also you do not need flag here, in condition use `!=` instead of `==`. If you want to show alert then you should use `alert()` instead of `console.log`

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.indexOf('+') != 0) {
      $(this).val(''); // clear input 
      console.log ("Phone number must start with +");    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

condition to test here must be:

```
 if (value.indexOf('+') !== 0) {
```

and you do not need the flag:

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/YX2Es/).

```
$('input').keyup(function(){    
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('+') !== 0) {
      $(this).val(''); // clear input       
      console.log ("Phone number must start with +");
    }
});
```